# How to keep a popup visible if show popup is on hover, not click. It hides as soon as you leave the marker

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am using clustering, and when the mouse hovers over one cluster it shows a popup.

The user needs to click on a link on that popup.

But as soon as the mouse leaves the marker, the popup closes.

What's an easy way to do this?

I've read and found there is this mousemove event, but i'm afraid that will be triggered many times and slow things down.

```
map.on('mousein ', 'clusters', function (e) {
  var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
  var id = e.features[0].id;

  map.getSource('users').getClusterLeaves(id, 50, 0, function(error, features){
    const html = features

    new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(coordinates)
    .setHTML(html)
    .addTo(map);
  })

});
```

Right now, it hides the popup as soon as you leave the marker.

I want the popup to be shown if user hover over marker and corresponding popup.